Well-definedness of the projection associated to the sheaf of germs of a presheaf
I'm currently reading Izu Vaisman's Cohomology and differential forms ($1973$) having never studied sheaf theory before, so I will briefly write down the definitions in case they don't match with modern ones or something of the sort.
Let $X$ be a topological space and $P$ be a presheaf of sets with basis $X$, i.e. a contravariant functor from the category $D(X)$ where the objects are the non-empty open subsets of $X$ and the morphisms are their inclusions to the category $\mathrm{Set}$ of, well, sets.
Such a functor can be interpreted as associating to each open subset $U$ a set $P(U)$ and to each inclusion $V \subset U$ a function $r^U_V : P(U) \to P(V)$ in such a way that:
$$r^U_U = \mathrm{id}_{P(U)}, \quad r^V_W \circ r^U_V = r^U_W \text{  if  } W \subset V \subset U$$
One example to have in mind is the presheaf of continuous functions on $X$ to another space $Y$, i.e. the presheaf where $P(U) = \mathcal{C}^0(U,Y)$ and $r^U_V$ is the restriction to $V$ of continuous maps defined on $U$.
What bothers me is located in the proof of Theorem II.2.2, during the construction of the so-called sheaf of germs of an arbitrary presheaf of sets $P$.
Let $x \in X$. The system $\{P(U), (r^U_V)_{V \subset U}\}$ where $U$ runs over the open sets of $X$ containing $x$ constitutes a directed inductive family for the order relation $\supset$, in $\mathrm{Set}$ where inductive limits always exist, hence we can consider:
$$F_x := \varinjlim_{U \owns x} P(U)$$
$F_x$ is comprised of equivalence classes of elements of the $P(U)$s, $U \owns x$, for the equivalence relation of being equal on a neighbourhood of $x$.
For $s \in P(U)$, denote by $[s]_x$ and call germ of $s$ at the point $x$ its class in $F_x$.
Finally, take $F := \bigcup_{x \in X} F_x$ endowed with the topology which has as a basis the family of the sets $\{[s]_x, x \in U\}$ for $U \in D(X)$ and $s \in P(U)$.
The map $p : [s]_x \in F \mapsto x \in X$ is then supposed to be a local homeomorphism, making $F$ a sheaf, hence its name of "sheaf of germs of $P$", but I have an issue with this, although I might just be missing something simple as per usual. It's not the local homeomorphism part, that I do understand, but rather the well-definedness of $p$ as a function to begin with:

Question: Seemingly no separability assumptions have been made on the topological space $X$, so it might not even be $T_0$, i.e. there might exist pairs of points in $X$ which are topologically indinstiguishable in the sense that all open sets which contain one of these points contains the other.
In that case, is the assignment $p : [s]_x \in F \mapsto x \in X$ even a function? If $[s]_x = [s']_y$, do we indeed have $x = y$, or would it be impossible to tell $x$ and $y$ apart?

My thought process is that, at least for the presheaves of continuous functions I mentioned as an example earlier, I don't quite see how germs of continuous functions would separate two topologically indistinguishable points, but also I haven't worked with such types of maybe not bizarre but at least unfamiliar topologies, as I usually work with normed spaces and maybe metric spaces at worst.
Sorry for the bother if it is a simple matter, and do feel free to re-tag and/or edit if/when appropriate.

$F_x$ is defined to be a set depending on $x$, and $F$ is defined to be a disjoint union of these sets.
So purely as a matter of definition, if $x\neq y$ then $F_x\cap F_y=\emptyset$, and likewise $[s]_x\neq [s]_y$.

What do you mean by "disjoint"? I feel like if $x$ and $y$ are both in exactly the same open sets, then $F_x = F_y$ altogether, but maybe you're saying that I should see $F_x$ more like an ordered pair $(x, F_x)$, so that even if $F_x = F_y$ there's still a distinction between $x$ and $y$?

You're on the right track! A "disjoint union" is a specific construction -- it is not just a union of sets which happen to be disjoint, rather, it a construction where we take a bunch of sets, force them to be disjoint by adding unique identifiers to their elements, and then form their union. An element of $\coprod_{x \in X} F_x$ ($\coprod$ is the symbol for this disjoint union operation) is a pair $(x, s)$ where $x$ is some element of $X$ and $s$ is some element of $F_x$. In other words, $\coprod_{x \in X} F_x = \bigcup_{x \in X} ({x} \times F_x)$.

If your text does not specify that the total space constructed here is meant to be a disjoint union, it is wrong :)

@diracdeltafunk I see, thank you!

@BrunoB There is certainly some abuse of notation here. $F_x$ is being used to refer to a certain direct limit, and also to the $x$-component of the disjoint union. But the direct limit itself is a hint: a direct limit is really defined by a universal property, not a particular definition, so it's not well-defined whether two equally-defined direct limits are equal, rather than just isomorphic. So in the first place we should assume they are disjoint. This is all standard but sloppy, and we should really use a notion like "dependent set", which is basically equivalent to your ordered pairs.
